# Pygame mixer.music.load() does not work with gTTs

Tags: python, pygame, text-to-speech, pydub, gtts

I'm trying to play a gTTs voice with `pygame.mixer.music.load()` only. I don't want to save the voice into a file, so I saved it into a `BytesIO` stream. `gTTs` returns `.mp3` audio which I know has limited support by `pygame`, so I tried to convert the `.mp3` audio to `.wav` using the `pydub` module, but I couldn't find a way to do so without saving it to a file. How can I fix this issue in any way possible?

```
from pygame import mixer
from gtts import gTTS

def play(buffer):
   buffer.seek(0)
   mixer.music.load(buffer) #Load the mp3
   print("Sound loaded. Time to play!")
   mixer.music.play() #Play it

def generate_voice(text, accent):
   mp3_fp = BytesIO()
   tts = gTTS(text)
   tts.write_to_fp(mp3_fp)
   return mp3_fp

text = "Hi there"
buffer = generate_voice(text, accent)
play(buffer)
```

The error returned by `pygame.mixer.music.load()`: `pygame.error: ModPlug_Load failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using `pydub` to convert the audio into a `wav` format:

```
def play(buffer):
   mixer.init() 
   mixer.music.load(buffer) #Load the mp3
   print("Sound loaded. Time to play!")
   mixer.music.play() #Play it

def generate_voice(text, lang):
   fp = BytesIO()
   wav_fp = BytesIO()
   tts = gTTS(text=text, lang=lang)
   tts.write_to_fp(fp)
   fp.seek(0)
   sound = AudioSegment.from_file(fp)
   wav_fp = sound.export(fp, format = "wav")
   return wav_fp
```